# Double pointer in recursion is required

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, data-structures

Why Double pointer is required with recursion if I want to add Node in linked-list. It should work with Single pointer.

Following code is not working for me

```
class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node* link;
    }*Ptr;
public:
    LinkedList()
    {
        Ptr = NULL;
    }

    void Add(int num)
    {
        /*Add(&Ptr, num);*/
        Add(Ptr, num);
    }

    void Add(Node* Ptr, int num)
    {
        Node* tmp = NULL;

        if (Ptr == NULL)
        {
            tmp = new Node;
            tmp->data = num;
            tmp->link = NULL;
            Ptr = tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            Add(Ptr->link, num);
        }
    }

    void Display()
    {
        Node *tmp;
        tmp = Ptr;

        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            cout <<tmp->data << endl;
            tmp = tmp->link;
        }
    }
}


int main() {

LinkedList l;

    l.Add(10);
    l.Add(20);
    l.Add(30);
    l.Add(40);
    l.Add(50);

    l.Display();

    _getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `Ptr = tmp;` means *nothing* to the caller in `Add()` (and in fact a memory leak ensues). You're use of a parameter `Ptr` with the same name as a member (`Ptr`) isn't helping (and generally ill-advised). You need to either pass your to-be-modified pointers by address or by reference. This being C++, you can guess the preference (whether you're allowed to use them or not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "double pointer" is required because you're changing the value of the pointer within the function.

Without even looking at your code, look at this very simple example:

```
void foo(int *x)
{
   x = new int[10];
}

int main()
{
   int *p = 0;
   foo(p);
   // why is p still NULL?
}
```

You will see that the value of `p` didn't change, even though the function obviously changes the parameter that was passed.  The problem is that `x` is a temporary variable, and any changes to `x` go away once the function exits.

To fix this problem, you must either pass a pointer to the pointer, or a reference to the pointer:

```
void foo(int** x)
{
    *x = new int[10];
}

void foo2(int *& x)
{
    x = new int[10];
}

int main()
{
    int *p = 0;
    foo(&p);  // now p will change
    delete [] p;

    p = 0;  // try again
    foo2( p );  // p also changes here
    delete [] p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i do when i have a problem of pointers, (what used to do), was to draw it, (specially with linked lists)...
I haven't run the code, but i am not entirely you can call your class 1...
And second it looks like your pointer of the list is always in the last element of the list... 
So if it runs, the only element it would read is the last one...
Try using the debugger and look at your adding process, or displaying...